# Azure App Service - Spring Boot - Hikari Errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have deployed `Spring Boot` application that has a Database based queue with jobs on `App Service`.

Yesterday I performed a few `Scale out` and `Scale in` operations while the application was working to see how it will behave.

At some point (not necessary related to scaling operations) application started to throw `Hikari` errors.

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1ae66f34 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1ef85079 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)
```

The following are stack traces from my scheduled job in spring and other information:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset by peer (Write failed)
Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer (Write failed)
```

Next the following stack of errors:

```
WARN 1 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@48d0d6da (This connection has been closed.). 

Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
```

The code which is invoked periodically - every 500 milliseconds is here:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${worker.delay}")
@Transactional
public void execute() {
    jobManager.next(jobClass).ifPresent(this::handleJob);
}
```

Update.
The above code is almost all the time doing nothing, since there was no traffic on the website.

Update2. I've checked `Postgres` logs and found this:

```
2020-07-11 22:48:09 UTC-5f0866f0.f0-LOG:  checkpoint starting: immediate force wait
2020-07-11 22:48:10 UTC-5f0866f0.f0-LOG:  checkpoint complete (240): wrote 30 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.046 s, sync=0.046 s, total=0.437 s; sync files=13, longest=0.009 s, average=0.003 s; distance=163 kB, estimate=13180 kB
2020-07-11 22:48:10 UTC-5f0866ee.68-LOG:  received immediate shutdown request
2020-07-11 22:48:10 UTC-5f0a3f41.8914-WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-07-11 22:48:10 UTC-5f0a3f41.8914-DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
// Same text about 10 times
2020-07-11 22:48:10 UTC-5f0866f2.7c-HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-07-11 22:48:10 UTC-5f0866ee.68-LOG:  src/port/kill.c(84): Process (272) exited OOB of pgkill.
2020-07-11 22:48:10 UTC-5f0866f1.fc-WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-07-11 22:48:10 UTC-5f0866f1.fc-DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2020-07-11 22:48:10 UTC-5f0866f1.fc-HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-07-11 22:48:10 UTC-5f0866ee.68-LOG:  archiver process (PID 256) exited with exit code 1
2020-07-11 22:48:11 UTC-5f0866ee.68-LOG:  database system is shut down
```

It looks like it is a problem with `Azure PostgresSQL` server and it closed itself. Am I reading this right?

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in your logs, have you tried setting maxLifetime property for the Hikari CP ? I think after setting that property this issue should be resolved.

Based on Hikari doc (https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) --
maxLifetime
`This property controls the maximum lifetime of a connection in the pool. An in-use connection will never be retired, only when it is closed will it then be removed. On a connection-by-connection basis, minor negative attenuation is applied to avoid mass-extinction in the pool. We strongly recommend setting this value, and it should be several seconds shorter than any database or infrastructure imposed connection time limit. A value of 0 indicates no maximum lifetime (infinite lifetime), subject of course to the idleTimeout setting. The minimum allowed value is 30000ms (30 seconds). Default: 1800000 (30 minutes)`

Comment: Thanks, I will play with this value, however I'd like to understand reason of this error - when I was using Azure Container Instances I didn't notice this problem.

Comment: 'Connection reset by peer' exception is coming because Database Server is closing the connection. But the application is still listening. So, on loosing the connection, the application responds with that exception. On the contrary, if the max-lifetime property is set and this time is less than Database connection limit, Spring application will close the connection before DB closing that connection. So, this should resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this would explain this... but one more thing I've found in DB logs. I updated the questions. Am I reading this right, that DB closed itself? I'm using azure postgres. Also the application logs  correlate with DB logs in time.

Comment: I have little idea on the postgres error. But I found this link which could be relevant - https://medium.com/@kobirosenstein/quick-postgresql-tip-warning-terminating-connection-because-of-6b55f0ba640b

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is the issue, I will dig a little more to this problem. Thank you for help!